# Spinner Error "Spinner adapter view type count must be 1"

Tags: android, parse-platform, spinner, illegalargumentexception, android-parsequeryadapter

I am using Parse.com in my application when I use ParseQueryAdapter in fragment to retrieve data and pass to a spinner an error as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Spinner adapter view type count must be 1
```

and application stops. However if I try ArrayAdapter it works. What could be the problem?

ParseQueryAdapter Code:

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> spnQuery=
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery(tableName);
                    return query;
                }
            };
    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), spnQuery);
    adapter.setTextKey(columnName);
    spnLecture.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParseQueryAdapter might be using SpinnerAdapter underneath.

One way to solve this issue is to lower your targetSdkVersion.
This error is being reported for targetSdkVersion of 21.

Please see here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79011

A long term solution is to fix the implementation of the adapter, which is not possible for your case until Parse team decides to fix it.

I had the same issue with SpinnerAdapter and got it working without peripheral damage using targetSdkVersion 19. Hope it helps!

Comment: I changed all my spinners to autocomplete. It looks cool now :D Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved the same problem just now, and you have two possible solutions:

a. Down the `targetSdkVersion` to 19

b. (My prefered) **Extend your parseadapter** and `@override` the `getViewTypeCount` with this code:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
     return 1;
}
```

This works for me :)