# Can't understand which class I should set as arguement in the constructor of ParseQueryAdapter class

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-spinner, illegalargumentexception, android-parsequeryadapter

I am new to android and Parse.com .I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328592/spinner-error-spinner-adapter-view-type-count-must-be-1). I am trying to get rid of an exception which is,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Spinner adapter view type count must be 1.

so I am extending the my adapter class to ParseQueryAdapter. here is my adapter class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class adapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> {

public adapter(Context context, Class clazz) {
    super(context, clazz);
}


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

}
```

from my activity I am calling

```
adapter parsequeryadapter = new adapter(this,/*WHICH CLASS I SHOULD PUT HERE*/);
```

I cant understand which class I should put in the second parameter. I have seen the ParseQueryAdapter class. the second parameter takes a class and that class has to be extended to ParseObject. here is the developers constructor of ParseQueryAdapter :

```
public ParseQueryAdapter(android.content.Context context, java.lang.Class<? extends com.parse.ParseObject> clazz) { /* compiled code */ }
```

I dont have any class which extends ParseObject or ParseUser. I have set the ParseUser from another activity which extends action bar activity. What can I do now? Please help.

Comment: Try this example https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html

Comment: Sorry. I didnt find any answer in this link. 
**ParseQueryAdapter(Context context, Class<? extends ParseObject> clazz)
Constructs a ParseQueryAdapter.**

Comment: my question is (Class<? extends ParseObject> clazz) in this parameter which class I should put??